# Can Mapnik 2.2 and Qgis 2.0.1 be installed together?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, mapnik

I'm using LM15 (== Ubuntu 13.04 Raring) with the Launchpad repos for Qgis Unstable 2.0.1 and Mapnik 2.2.0.

Quantum wants libgdal1h;
Mapnik wants libgdal1. As soon as I install one, the other gets uninstalled. Is it possible to install them both together?

I'm willing to try compiling from scratch if that's the only way to get things working.

Comment: I'll see if I can add mapnik to the unstable repo tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ubuntugis, you're on the naughty list this Christmas because you don't play nicely with the other kids. The conflict between libgdal1 and libgdal1h also prevented me installing postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 from the pgdg repo's.

Workaround, I'm not using the ubuntugis-unstable repo for the time being. I'm using the 'official' qgis repository instead.

Answer (score 1):

My advise is: first install QGIS and GDAL 1.10 from Ubuntugis packages, then follow the Mapnik [build instructions](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UbuntuInstallation). Mapnik compile time is much shorter than QGIS one, and I followed this route without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you installing QGIS and mapnik from?

I'm on 12.04 and have qgis 2.01 installed and mapnik 2.2.

I don't recall which one I installed first, but I have qgis installed from the [ubuntu-gis unstable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable) and mapnik from the [mapnik PPA.](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UbuntuInstallation)

Comment: From the same PPA's. I've tried mapnik 2.2 and 2.3-nightly.